# ImportError on "import feather" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, feather

I am trying to install feathers on my environment but it keeps crashing on "import feather".
the error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1d29cbb85491> in <module>
----> 1 import feather

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\feather\__init__.py in <module>
     15 # flake8: noqa
     16 
---> 17 from feather.api import (read_dataframe, write_dataframe,
     18                          FeatherError, FeatherReader, FeatherWriter)
     19 from feather.version import version as __version__

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\feather\api.py in <module>
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 
---> 15 from pyarrow.feather import (read_feather as read_dataframe,  # noqa
     16                              write_feather as write_dataframe,
     17                              FeatherError,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py in <module>
     52 
     53 
---> 54 from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
     55 from pyarrow.lib import (null, bool_,
     56                          int8, int16, int32, int64,

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

any help in solving this issue.
In the Anaconda Prompt, I used

```
conda install -c conda-forge feather-format
```

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? I found an issue in github that recommend's launching PyCharm from the command line to ensure the correct PATH variable when loading the library: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508#issuecomment-452382980

Comment: @mgrollins no, I am using Spyder  - anaconda environment.